# Get feedback why android app purchase has been cancelled?

Tags: android, cancellation, purchase-order

I have published my first android app and its quite different from iPhone.

On some android app purchases I got cancellation of the order. When I check the orders I get a reason saying: Cancellation requested from phone.

In the upper left corner of the screen there is an email contact of the purchaser - so I sent emails to those who have cancelled but never got a feedback.

Is this the right way to get feedback in these cases?
How can I find out the reason for cancellation?
I realized that there are problems with purchase processing in some cases (I asked a friend to purchase my app) - does this happen often and is this a main cause for cancellation ?

Many thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In android, a customer can cancel a purchase so long as they do it before 30? mins have elapsed. It's been my experience that a fair number of app sales end up being canceled by customers. I believe this is because the customers are trying the app and finding that it's not something they actually want to pay for.

As far as cancelation reason, I think there's no good way for that data to flow back to developers yet (I've never seen a real reason given on cancelations that have happened in my apps).

Does this happen often? In the case of my app, yes.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in way to figure out why someone cancelled the order (for example, the uninstallation survey is not available to developers).

Contacting the buyers will work, but honestly I would advise against it.
Even though as a developer, it would be useful, as a user I personally would be rather annoyed if I was contacted by the developer every time I tried out an application and didn't choose to keep it. One of the best parts of the Market is the no-strings-attached trials. You should look at the trial period and refunds, not as people who purchased your application and then changed their mind, but as people who weren't going to purchase it, but decided to give it a shot because there were no consequences. I know that I have purchased applications that I wouldn't have otherwise because I was able to try them out.